# KeyDown Event Not Firing After Drag Drop Operation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom editable text box in a template for a TreeViewItem. The items
can be edited when F2 key is pressed. If not in edit mode, when the item is
clicked, a drag and drop operation is triggered.  This is my template for the
editable tree view item:

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="editableHierarchyNodeTemplate"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding ContainedParameter}"
                              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource treeItemTemplateSelector}">

        <ut:EditBox Text="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=TwoWay}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="EditBox_PreviewMouseDown" PreviewKeyDown="EditBox_KeyDown"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The EditBox is custom control which simply switches from a "read only" to editable TextBox. In the "EditBox_KeyDown" method I simply set the IsInEditMode property of the EditBox to true, and it does its magic. However, this event is not fired
after I handle the "PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" as follows:

```
  private void EditBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataObject data = (new DataObject());
        data.SetData("Parameter", (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Parameter);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.All);
    }
```

I assume that, once the drag drop operation is started, it simply absorbs all key
events. How do I cancel this?

Comment: handled = false ? tried ?

Comment: Probably a focus problem.  You'd normally set the focus on the control when you left-click it and then it gets the key events.  But that no longer happens, you swallow the left click by starting a D+D.  Workaround is to only call DoDragDrop() after the mouse has moved far enough.  Record the MouseDown position and use MouseMove to detect it moving while the left button is down.

Comment: That is a good idea, but won't the focus be swallowed anyway, no matter where do I start the drag and drop operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, in fact, the lost focus. Important part of solving the issue was that my EditBox was displaying uneditable TextBox when the items is not being edited. TextBox is a focusable control. I chnaged this to TextBlock, which is not focusable.
For drag and drop operations I ended up using the following approach:

http://www.wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html

The combination of these two changes solved the problem.